# threejs r82 plyloader with PointsMaterial and Points

Tags: three.js

I'm upgrading my threejs from r75 to r82, but now I have an issue loading my PLY file using PLYLoader. Nothing shows in the view, and I don't get any console error messages. I noticed that in r82 - the loader now uses a buffer geometry.

This is how I'm trying to use the loader:

```
var loader = new THREE.PLYLoader();
    loader.load(plyUrl, function (geometry) {
    geometry.computeFaceNormals();
    var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors, size: .002});
    var object = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    scene.add(object);
});
```

The threejs example PLY files work fine for me, but not when I try to use my custom made PLY file to render points. Here's the [example PLY](https://www.aquifiscan.tk/static/tmp/645460a726d64fb5bc831ffa0e4c9d22/scanlive/aggregatedpcl.ply) I'm using. I noticed the example files have a "property list uchar int vertex_indices" while mine does not. Is that necessary? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can make a jsfiddle if necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working again. All I needed to do was convert the geometry before creating the points.

var geo = new THREE.Geometry().fromBufferGeometry( geometry );